# Reverse and SQL query

Tags: sql

I have an SQL query that works correctly...

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM g_lead_d a JOIN g_lead b ON b.id = a.l_id WHERE b.date_posted LIKE '%$2014-01-01%' AND a.form_id LIKE '654' AND a.field_number = '22'
```

This returns all of the values with field_number 22, what I would like to do now is run this query again but reversed so it shows me all of the values without field_number 22.

How should I approach?

---

****UPDATE****

I am know trying to use this query....

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM g_lead_d a JOIN g_lead b ON b.id = a.l_id WHERE b.date_posted LIKE '%$2014-01-01%' AND a.form_id LIKE '654' AND a.field_number <> '22'
```

This is giving me an unexpected result and instead of returning the expected result **10** it is returning **27483**

My data set is huge but a simplified sample is below.....

```
g_lead_d
id  |    l_id  |  form_id  |  field_number  |  value
----------------------------------------------------
1   |     1    |    654    |      22        | value1
2   |     2    |    654    |      22        | value8        
3   |     3    |    654    |      53        | value3
4   |     4    |    654    |      67        | value4
5   |     5    |    654    |      22        | value8
6   |     6    |    654    |      26        | value2
7   |     7    |    654    |      22        | value9


g_lead
id  |  form_id  |  date_created
-------------------------------
1   |    654    |   2014-01-01        
2   |    654    |   2014-01-01        
3   |    654    |   2014-01-01        
4   |    654    |   2014-01-01        
5   |    654    |   2014-01-01
6   |    654    |   2014-01-01        
7   |    654    |   2014-01-01
```

Comment: have you trie `a.field_number <> '22'`

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using

```
a.field_number = '22'
```

Try with

```
a.field_number <> '22'
```

So `field_number` will not equals `'22'`

Comment: When I do that it ignores the a.form_id part for some reason

Comment: @fightstarr20 You are using `a.form_id LIKE '654'` which is equal to `a.form_id = '654'`. Maybe there is no rows that satisfy your conditions ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS count 
FROM g_lead_d a JOIN g_lead b ON b.id = a.l_id 
WHERE b.date_posted LIKE '%$2014-01-01%' AND a.form_id LIKE '654' 
AND a.field_number <> '22'
```